# Odd or Even number of transpositions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that if I have any permutation, this permutation can be written as the product of transpositions. Now the number of these transpositions may be odd or even depending on my permutation. I also know that any transposition can be written as the product of simple transpositions (the pair $(i,i+1)$). So this means that any permutation can be written as the product of simple transpositions and the number of these transpositions may be odd or even depending on the permutation. Have I missed anything?

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: that my statement is correct or not?

Comment: No, you haven't missed anything, and yes, your statement is correct :-)

Comment: You may have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation

Comment: Please help me. Thank you. 

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423297/how-to-explain-that-1-32-4-1-3-2-4

Answer (score 1):

No, you have not missed anything. But you should probably state explicitly that no permutation can be written both as an even number of transpositions and an odd number of transpositions.